# OpenCart API login returns empty string instead of success or fail message

Tags: php, api, opencart

I had created a test store in OpenCart. I try to login the API by http://opencart.frontierforce.com/index.php?route=api/login, but I got the result like this:

[image]

I tried the same for their demo API and it is returning the correct message.

I have checked on the setting on API, user, user permission and allow my IP to access on the API, but I still cannot get the correct message. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For you API endpoint try using

```
http://opencart.frontierforce.com/index.php?route=api/account/login
```

Since all the paths are changed for openkart API.

And you need to append the session key to the API.